# Question about the tangent space of a manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I am studying manifolds by myself and I am following this note https://www.math.toronto.edu/laithy/367/367.html
but i am confused from the definition of a tangent space
The definition is showing in the picture [image]

1. what does he mean by $u^{i}$ in the denomator of the formula of $v(f)$ ?is it the coordinate $(u^1,.....,u^{m})$ of $ \mathbb{R}^{m}$ ?,how we can compute the value of $a$ in the fomrula of $v(f)$
2. I have seen many books but I could not find any book gives an example of computing the tangent space I hope that someone can give me an example of computing the tangent space in detail to make it more clear for me.

Comment: Please don't use pictures, and if you do at least crop them...

Comment: The $u^{i}$ in the denominator means that you're taking the partial derivative of the function $f\circ \varphi^{-1}(u^{1},...,u^{n})$ with respect to the $i$-th variable.

Comment: 1. Yes. Think of $v$ as a definition and not a formula. You don't have to compute $a$, the tangent space is the collection of all such linear maps.

Comment: As for your second question, what do you mean by "computing the tangent space"? When you're working with an (abstract) manifold $M$, there is not much more to say about $T_{p}(M)$, apart from that the vectors $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}},...,\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{n}}$ form a basis.

Comment: Nevertheless, if $N$ is a submanifold of $M$, then you can compute $T_{p}(N)$ as a subspace of $T_{p}(M)$.

Comment: @Farch lubinus can you give an example ( in $\mathbb{R}^n)$